# How does one identify an engine?

Tags: engine

My sister recently purchased a used car in a private party sale. When we went to change the oil the filter listed online doesn't fit. Instead of finding a screw on filter there is a hard plastic plug with a paper filter inside. We suspect that the engine may have been swapped at some point and would like to identify the engine. How do we go about identifying the engine?

Comment: Many components will have the manufactirer name or symbol.

Comment: I'm thinking this question is a bit too broad. I could *probably* write down how you could figure out what engine is in the car, but then it'd probably be 20 pages long, because there is no universal way of doing it. Every manufacturer is going to be different in how they mark their engines so you can verify what is there.

Comment: @paulster2 I think OP is asking for the first 10 lines of your 20 pages. In other words, what are the starting points for a more focussed question?

Comment: @NL_Derek - Might be, but that's not what the question says. Starting points won't even get us started on what's needed to decipher which engine is in their vehicle.